# unable to utilize my licenses

Tags: licenses, community, partner

Unable to access my partner community licenses. I have 19 Available but the option when creating a new user, as far a licensing goes, only allows me to choose create chatter free/chatter (in general) accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it from the contact....

1. Create an account
2. Create a contact under that account
3. On the account, click enable as portal/partner or whatever it is
4. On the contact click enable as community user

follow the On Screen Instructions

Away you go....